# Loopback POST array of entry?

Tags: post, loopbackjs, loopback4

I want to insert 10 entries with one query against 10 queries.

I read that it's possible to do it by sending an array like this :
[image]

But I get this error:
[image]

Do I need to set something? I don't know what to do at all.

Repo with a sample : https://github.com/mathias22osterhagen22/loopback-array-post-sample

Edit:
people-model.ts:

```js
import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';

@model()
export class People extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  id?: number;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;


  constructor(data?: Partial<People>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface PeopleRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type PeopleWithRelations = People & PeopleRelations;
```

Comment: can u also add model file in question and I tried adding array to create endpoint and it did create multiple entries at once.

Comment: I just edited my post + I added a repo with the project.
How did you manage to "adding array to create endpoint"? sorry but I'm not sure that I understood.

Comment: I mean I passed array in body, as u showed in your example and it worked.

Comment: And you didn't add or change nothing into the model file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your code was :

> "name": "ValidationError", "message": "The `People` instance is not
>   valid. Details: `0` is not defined in the model (value: undefined);
>   `1` is not defined in the model (value: undefined); `name` can't be
>   blank (value: undefined).",

Here in above as in your @requestBody schema, you are applying to insert a single object property, where as in your body are sending the array of [people] object.

As you can see  in your people.model.ts you have declared property name to be required, so system finds for the property "name", which obviously not available in the given array of object as primary node.

As you are passing index array, so its obvious error that you don't have any property named 0 or 1, so it throws error.

The below is the code hat you should apply to get insert the multiple, items of the type.

```
@post('/peoples', {
 responses: {
    '200': {
      description: 'People model instance',
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(People)
        }
      },
    },
  },
})
async create(
  @requestBody({
    content: {
      'application/json': {
        schema: {
          type: 'array',
          items: getModelSchemaRef(People, {
            title: 'NewPeople',
            exclude: ['id'],
          }),
        }
      },
    },
  })
  people: [Omit<People, 'id'>]
): Promise<{}> {
  people.forEach(item => this.peopleRepository.create(item))
  return people;
}
```

You can also use this below

```
Promise<People[]> {
  return await this.peopleRepository.createAll(people)
}
```

You can pass the array of your people model by modifying the request body.If you need more help you can leave comment. 
I think you have a clear solution now. "Happy Loopbacking :)"

Comment: still giving following error `"The People instance is not valid. Details: 0 is not defined in the model (value: undefined); name can't be blank (value: undefined)."`

Comment: @Madaky I think that will just change "array" on the interface

Comment: @RohitAmbre, You have not applied the example as I suggested, Now updating the the complete code.

Comment: @Madaky it's working well thank you. The issue I opened on the git link here then there is the link back to the issue: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5716